# Add page to block in drupal pages , throw error 502

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

When I try to add a custom block and then select the page edit option, it throws an error called **502 Bad Request**.
any idea....

I tried create a new page and add same block, still the same issue here.
Is there any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: May be this solution will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1647945/20347478

Comment: enable logging errors and check if you get any errors.